# Why I get error Invalid Number and what does it mean?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand what is wrong in my query, but whatever I try I get same error.

```
 SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
  WHERE uta.UserID = 381
  AND uta.Approved = 0
  AND 2020-01-20 BETWEEN uta.StartDate AND uta.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

StartDate and EndDate are store as `DATE` and I pass format which is correctly.
I try to change `format` but nothing happened, same error.
I also try to remove `time` but also nothink happened.

Here is table definition:

```
ABSENCETYPE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ANSWER  VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)
APPROVED    NUMBER(10,0)
COMMENT_    CLOB
DAYS    NUMBER(10,0)
ENDDATE DATE
ISANSWERED  NUMBER(10,0)
ISREJECTED  NUMBER(10,0)
STARTDATE   DATE
USERABSENCEID   NUMBER(10,0)
USERHASSEEN VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)
USERID  NUMBER(10,0)
WIDTH   NUMBER(10,0)
```

Some output which I expect needs to look like following

```
StartDate       EndDate
2020-01-01      2020-01-28
```

Comment: Don't pass dates as strings. Should be ` and date '2020-01-01' between ...`.

Comment: You mean without ' '

Comment: Sorry, formatting got lost. I meant `and date '2020-01-01' between ...`. Date literal includes keyword DATE and date value enclosed into single quotes in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Nope :( Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've modified query you initially wrote; now it really *is* invalid.

Should be - according to info you posted:

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate
  FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
 WHERE     uta.UserID = 381
       AND uta.Approved = 0
       AND DATE '2020-01-20' BETWEEN uta.StartDate
                                 AND uta.EndDate + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

- `userid` is `NUMBER` so yes - you can use `381`
- `approved` is `NUMBER` so yes - you can use `0`
- `startdate` and `enddate` are `DATE`s so yes - you can add `interval '1' day`

There's nothing else that could be wrong here (or, at least, I don't see it).